# counting letters of selected items, 2 listboxes

Tags: c#, count, listbox

how do i count letters from one SELECTED ITEM in first listbox, and then give that number in another listbox.

**so if i have 5 items in 1. listbox, and select 3. item, in second listbox should write: 
"Third item contains x letters"

edit:
***sorry, here's what ive done so far, but the problem is it counts all letters in every item, and in 2. listbox i got answer for every row, not for selected one.

```
 private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0, j;
            char letter;
            string str;
            while (i < lst1.Items.Count)
            {
                letter = Convert.ToString(lst1.Items[i]); 
                for (j = 0; j < str.Length; j++) 
                {
                    char = str[j];                
                }
                lst2.Items.Add("In " + i + " row there are "+ original.Length + " letters");
                i++;
            }
```

edit2:

```
namespace CountLetters
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listboxA.Items.Add(txt1.Text);
            txt1.Clear();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        int length = (listboxA.SelectedValue as string).Length;
        String out = (listboxA.SelectedIndex + "Has"+ len + "Character").ToString();
        listboxB.Items.Add(out);

        }

    }
}
```

form image: http://postimg.org/image/yn9in6er7/

this doesen't work either, don't know what's the problem.

Comment: is this your homework or what ?? try to make an effort first

Comment: Why would you want a listbox to display a single result? The solution is simple, but that's not how we operate on SO. You've shown no intention on solving it on your own. Any basic winforms tutorial covers the knowledge that you need to work the problem out.

Comment: Please show your efforts so far and give details of the specific problem you are facing?

Comment: sorry ppl, i've added details and code.I've searched for solution and couldn't find it, still stuck on this one, pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two listbox say listboxA and listboxB and some items to the listbox.
if you are using WPF then you can do the following.

```
listboxA.Items.Add("One");
listboxA.Items.Add("OneTwo");
```

and inside selectionChanged event you just do

```
int length = listBoxA.SelectedItem.ToString().Length;;
String output = (listboxA.SelectedIndex + "Has"+ len + "Character").ToString();
listboxB.Items.Add(output);
```

Comment: if thats the answer you can mark that as answer so in the futurefor someone else it will help